# Select class name in HTML Parser containing extra words

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape a web page. I want to get reviews. But the reviews are of three categories, some are positive, some are neutral and some are negative. I am using html parser and have accessed many tags. But for the class which can be in three categories, how can I get them:

```
<div class="review positive" title="" style="background-color: #00B551;">9.3</div>
<div class="review negative" title="" style="background-color: #FF0000;">4.8</div>
<div class="review neutral" title="" style="background-color: #FFFF00;">6</div>
```

I have a python container for each div containing each item:

```
# finds each product from the store page
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})`

for container in containers:
    title = container.findAll(a).text #This gives me titles
    ##Similarly I need the reviews of each of them here
    review = container.findAll("div", {"class": "review "}))#along with review there is positive, neutral and negative word also according to the type of review
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regex, you can get the classes that contain the substring `"review"`.

```
import re

for container in containers:
    title = container.findAll(a).text #This gives me titles

    review = container.findAll("div", {"class": re.compile(r'review')})
```

**See the difference:**

```
html = '''<div class="review positive" title="" style="background-color: #00B551;">9.3</div>
<div class="review negative" title="" style="background-color: #FF0000;">4.8</div>
<div class="review neutral" title="" style="background-color: #FFFF00;">6</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
review = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'review '})
print ('No regex: ',review)

print('\n')

review = soup.findAll("div", {"class": re.compile(r'review')})
print ('Regex: ',review)
```

**Output:**

```
No regex:  []


Regex:  [<div class="review positive" style="background-color: #00B551;" title="">9.3</div>, <div class="review negative" style="background-color: #FF0000;" title="">4.8</div>, <div class="review neutral" style="background-color: #FFFF00;" title="">6</div>]
```